# No access to the created input

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I added an extra field to the `cart.php` using Snippet plugin.

```
function action_woocommerce_cart_coupon() { 
    echo '<input type="text" name="card" class="input-text" id="card" value="" placeholder="Card" />';
}; 
         
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon', 'action_woocommerce_cart_coupon');
```

And I would my own validation when the `Apply coupon` button is clicked. Unfortunately, There is no way I can get value of this new field.

I downloaded the post in several places but I don't have access to this field.

```
if ( ! empty( $_POST['card'] ) ) {
    echo '<script>console.log("' . $_POST['card'] . '")</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script>console.log("PHP error")</script>';
}
```

```
function action_woocommerce_applied_coupon( $coupon_code ) { 
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            echo '<script>console.log("' . $key . " " . $value . '")</script>';
        }
}; 
         
add_action( 'woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'action_woocommerce_applied_coupon');
```

**Output:**

```
security ac228a43c2
coupon_code 1
```

I understand this is called in `class-wc-cart.php` but I can't understand how I could pass this field to this method. Is anyone able to tell me something about this?

I will also appreciate any other ideas to solve this problem.

Comment: In cart page nothing is posted, so should need to find out how to use ajax as cart events does (apply a coupon, remove item, update quantity…)

Comment: Thanks!!! i understood how it works. I will just add that you also need to edit min.js file..